# SQL Alchemy AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I've been creating a database of users who can favourite items in an online shopping site. I seem to be getting this error even though when I type out b.title and board they both print "u'board name'".
It should be so that when someone checks a board checkbox, the relationship of that item of clothing to the board should be added to the database.

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="boards_list">
          <table class="table is-striped">
            {% for board in boards %}
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label class="checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="board_titles" value="{{board.title}}"/>
                </label>
                <a href="#">{{board.title}}</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </table>

          <div class="field is-grouped">
            <div class="control">
              <button type="submit" class="button is-small">Add To Favs</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

This is code from the Jinja2 template shown above. The following is code from the roots:

```
if request.method =="POST":
            f_b_titles = request.form.getlist("board_titles")
            clothing = Clothing.query.filter_by(name = name).first()
            userid = int(current_user.id)
            clothingid = int(clothing.id)
            for b in boards:
                for board in f_b_titles:
                    if b.title == board:
                        fav_relationship = Favourites_relationship(user_id = userid, clothing_id = clothingid, favs_board = b.title)
                        db.session.add(fav_relationship)
                        db.session.commit()
                        flash('Added favourite to mood board!', 'success')
```

and finally, code from db models:

```
class Favourites_relationship(db.Model, UserMixin):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), unique=True, nullable=False)
clothing_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clothing.id'),nullable=False)
board_title = db.Column(db.Unicode, db.ForeignKey('favourites_board.title'), nullable=False)
```

and:

```
class Favourites_board(db.Model, UserMixin):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
favourites_relationships = db.relationship('Favourites_relationship', backref='favs_board', lazy=True)
```

More info on errors:

```
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/leawhitelaw/Desktop/online_shop_data/flaskshop/routes.py", line 97, in product_details
fav_relationship = Favourites_relationship(user_id = userid, clothing_id = clothingid, favs_board = b.title)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
fav_relationship = Favourites_relationship(user_id = userid, clothing_id = clothingid, favs_board = b)
```

Basically what the error is saying that you can only assign `Favourites_board` instances (e.g. `fb = Favourites_board()`) to a relationship.

So assuming boards is a list of `Favourites_board` instances, you can just assign a board (`b`) from that list to `favs_board=...`.

Comment: That appears to have fixed it, I haven't tested whether it's entered the database correctly yet but the success banner is appearing now. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
board_title = db.Column(db.Unicode, db.ForeignKey('favourites_board.title'), nullable=False)
```

this line is wrong

from [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html)

> When using the Unicode type, it is only appropriate to pass Python
>   unicode objects, and not plain str. If a plain str is passed under
>   Python 2, a warning is emitted. If you notice your application
>   emitting these warnings but you’re not sure of the source of them, the
>   Python warnings filter, documented at
>   http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html, can be used to turn
>   these warnings into exceptions which will illustrate a stack trace:

Since you are passing raw values from the form and that is expecting python objects.

try using:

db.**String**

db.Text

or db.Unicodetext